# get the control with a certain name provided as a string in c#

Tags: c#, controls, instance

i have the name of a control in a string and I want to manipulate the control, how do i turn the string into the current form instance of that control in c#?

e.g.

```
string controlName = "Button1";
```

What goes here?

```
button1.text = "Changed";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Button button1 = (Button)this.Controls[controlName];
```

Comment: Thanks all three of you, I knew it was simple once you know how!

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up the control in the controls collections, then cast it to the correct type.  Is this in WPF , WinForms or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the form, you could write (c#)

```
this.Controls["Button1"].Text = "Changed";
```

I suppose, this could be the syntax in vb.net

```
Me.Controls("Button1").Text = "Changed"
```

EDIT: I don't know, if that would compile. @Binary Worrier is right

```
Button btn1 = this.Controls["Button1"] as Button;
btn1.Text = "Changed";
```

Comment: This one ended up working more reliably in the end, and compiles fine for me, thanks :)